# How do I use windows 8 search easily in windows 10?

Tags: search

Windows search everything is much better and faster in finding stuff than cortana

I created a short cut to it on desktop.

The shortcut points to

```
%windir%\system32\rundll32.exe -sta {C90FB8CA-3295-4462-A721-2935E83694BA}
```

I sometimes want to access that more easily.

I want to search cortana for "search"

I cannot find that short cut even though it's clearly located at

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start
  Menu\Programs
```

I wonder if I can type search in cortana and found that short cut. What would be the best way?

Pinning search to start menu doesn't show up anything. Inf fact I have no idea what it's for because the start menu remain the way it is.

In fact, I created a folder  Search in

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Search

Neither the folder or anything in it shows up

Comment: I created an identical shortcut on my Windows 10 desktop.  I right-clicked it directly and tried both "Pin to Start" and "Pin to Taskbar".  They both worked for me - did that not work for you?

Comment: It looks like my action moved the shortcut to the user-specific folder (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs).  Maybe that's the trick?

Comment: It didn't work for me. In fact, search doesn't show up in all apps at all. Also I want to see this for all users. Pin to task bar works though.